# Page returns exception in IIS7.5, runs fine in VS2010 debug

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Adding some code to an existing MVC webpage.  All other parts of the site continue to work fine.  Running Debug in VS2010, the code functions correctly.  After uploading to IIS 7.5 it returns the exception below.  Any ideas?  Can provide additional code if needed.

Thanks

---

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: String

   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Int32.Parse(String s)
   at McCarterMobile.Controllers.CartController.RemoveContribution(FormCollection form) in V:\Google Drive\Websites\Mobile Site\McCarterMobile\Controllers\CartController.cs:line 391
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
```

---

Here is the controller code.

```
383            public ActionResult RemoveContribution(FormCollection form)
384        {
385            string sessionKey = "";
386
387            if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
388            {
389                {
390                    sessionKey = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(HttpContext.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).UserData;
391                    repository.RemoveContribution(sessionKey, int.Parse(form["Ref_Num"]));
392                }
393                return RedirectToAction("Index");
394            }
395            else
396            {
397                return RedirectToAction("File Not Found", "Errors");
398            }
399        }
```

---

Here is the cshtml code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RemoveContribution", "Cart"))
{
<input type="submit" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="right" />
<input type=hidden name=Ref_Num value='@c.RefNum' />
}
```

---

Comment: Looks like `form["Ref_Num"]` and therefore `@c.RefNum` is null...

Comment: The error says about System.Number.StringToNumber, and form["Ref_Num"] is null. Does your method implements [HttpPost] or did you check value of @c.RefNum?

Comment: Here is the trace.axd at the POST
[link](http://www.grandtheater.org/media/trace.htm)
showing the form collecttion and the Ref_Num value

Comment: The error seems to imply otherwise.  Suggest you extract the RefNum value at the top of the action, throw a try..catch block around it and verify that you can extract that value first.

Comment: Extracting the value at the top of the action still produces different results depending on where the application is running.  In VS2010 the value is not null and passes.  In IIS 7.5 the value is null and throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The MVC framework will handle the type conversions and such for you if you let it:

```
public ActionResult RemoveContribution(int? Ref_Num = null)
{
    if (Ref_Num == null)
    {
        // report an error or whatever
    }
    else
    {
        // do something with Ref_Num
    }
}
```

There's a lot of code in the MVC framework to support this stuff so that you don't have to keep dealing with type conversions and such.